# Take a String of random letters, and generate all the words these letters can make

Tags: vb.net

So i have an assignment to make, which basically wants the user to input random letters to a textfield, or pressing the random letter generator button, and then after the push of a button, it will appear the words these letters can make inside listboxes. I have 10 listboxes. Depending on the word's length, it will appear in the corresponding listbox. Here is a code i made. My code creates permutations, and appears them in the listboxes. It's not the best way, since it could take hours to find permutations of an 11 length string. But my question now is, how can make my code check inside an array which contains 200000 English words, for the legal words and make them appear in the listboxes?

```
 Dim t As Date = Date.Now





    Dim chars() As Char = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 1 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars



                RankBox2.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & Environment.NewLine)





            Next
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 2 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    RankBox3.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & Environment.NewLine)

                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        RankBox4.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & Environment.NewLine)
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 4 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            RankBox5.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & Environment.NewLine)
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 5 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                RankBox6.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & Environment.NewLine)
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 6 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                For Each c6 As Char In chars
                                    RankBox7.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & Environment.NewLine)
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 7 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                For Each c6 As Char In chars
                                    For Each c7 As Char In chars
                                        RankBox8.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & Environment.NewLine)
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 8 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                For Each c6 As Char In chars
                                    For Each c7 As Char In chars
                                        For Each c8 As Char In chars
                                            RankBox9.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 & Environment.NewLine)
                                        Next
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 9 Then
        For Each c0 As Char In chars
            For Each c1 As Char In chars
                For Each c2 As Char In chars
                    For Each c3 As Char In chars
                        For Each c4 As Char In chars
                            For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                For Each c6 As Char In chars
                                    For Each c7 As Char In chars
                                        For Each c8 As Char In chars
                                            For Each c9 As Char In chars
                                                RankBox10.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 & c9 & Environment.NewLine)
                                            Next
                                        Next
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 10 Then
            For Each c0 As Char In chars
                For Each c1 As Char In chars
                    For Each c2 As Char In chars
                        For Each c3 As Char In chars
                            For Each c4 As Char In chars
                                For Each c5 As Char In chars
                                    For Each c6 As Char In chars
                                        For Each c7 As Char In chars
                                            For Each c8 As Char In chars
                                                For Each c9 As Char In chars
                                                    For Each c10 As Char In chars
                                                        RankBox11.Items.Add(c0 & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 & c6 & c7 & c8 & c9 & c10 & Environment.NewLine)
                                                    Next
                                                Next
                                            Next
                                        Next
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next

        End If


    MsgBox(Date.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds & " seconds")
```

Comment: Wow, those are some beautiful for each statements you have there.

Comment: Have you considered using recursion?

Comment: Rather than generate up to 100,000,000,000 random strings then check if each is in the list of 200,000 words, it would be around 500,000 times faster to check if each of the 200,000 words could be spelt with the letters available.

Comment: i found a way to find legal words, now i need to find a way to prevent duplicates, for instance "ab" would also check "aa" and "bb". anyway thanks guys for the tips.